# How to upgrade PHP version in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

The Envato Market plugin requires PHP version 5.4+, plugin is currently NOT ACTIVE. How to deal with this problem?
Can anybody help me, please?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: PHP 5.4 is _ancient_. You're running something even older than that? Upgrading will depend entirely on your hosting environment. Can you [edit] your question and tell us a bit about that? (And you really, _really_ should upgrade PHP to at least version 7.1.)

Comment: Assuming you have your website hosted somewhere, this question is probably best directed at your ISP to see how to do it.

Comment: I am running Wordpress theme on the website. The admin platform says like that. Which version should I upgrade to and why?

Comment: …I have no idea what that means, @supercoder720. Who set your website up originally? You may want to get them involved in this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please contact the hosting provider to upgrade the PHP version.